# AJAX search using JSP and Spring

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a dropdown option field in JSP page. Dropdown values coming from MySQL database with help of Spring controller.

```
controller@ 
@RequestMapping(value = "/addBank1")
public ModelAndView  addBank(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String  entityType) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allbankAccounts = accService
        .getAllbankAccounts(entityType);
    model.addAttribute("allbankAccounts", allbankAccounts);
}
```

In JSP am using like:

```
<p class="text-muted font-13">
    <strong>Bank name </strong>                               
        <span class="m-l-15">
            <form:select class="form-control" path="empQufnId" title="Select" id="report">
                <form:option value="" label="Select  bank name" />
                <c:forEach items="${allbankAccounts}" 
        var="sal" varStatus="status"
                <form:option path="empQufnId" value="${sal.bankId}" >${sal.bankName}</form:option>     
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
```

Comment: what do you want suggestions for?

Comment: Make your question to be clear. you did not mention the issue here..

Comment: i need example for ajax search using jsp and spring..

Comment: Is it production code of some banking-system?

Comment: no,My question simple Oleksii...i need simple ajax search example dropdown values should be comes from database  so how to use i dont no am new for spring and jsp

Answer (score 0):

please to try below code :

On your controller :

```
Map<Integer, String> allbankAccounts = accService.getAllbankAccounts(entityType);
model.addAttribute("allbankAccounts", allbankAccounts);
```

On you JSP :

```
<form:select class="form-control" path="empQufnId" title="Select" id="report">
       <form:option value="0" label="Select bank name"/>
       <form:options items="${allbankAccounts}" />
</form:select>
```

Comment: my code is working fine messaoud ..... i need ajax search i e autocomplete  example by using spring and jsp ,

Comment: Ajax autocompete for select bankList?! i not understand your request, the autocomplete must be on input text